# Django 'python manage.py runserver' has from config import* error

Tags: python, django, import, config, manage.py

I have an error when i use django.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/ghk/djangoprojects/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/ghk/djangoprojects/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 308, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/ghk/djangoprojects/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/ghk/djangoprojects/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/ghk/djangoprojects/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/ghk/djangoprojects/lab-in-the-wild/labinthewild/settings.py", line 18, in <module>
    from config import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

If I command 'python manage.py runserver', it show this error.

Comment: What is `from config import *` supposed to import?

Comment: I clone this project from git. In settings.py, there is `# Custom configuration file
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
from config import *`

Comment: Add all relevant information and code to your question.

Comment: ok, i will edit my question with code

Comment: oh, i can't add my code to my question because the code is so long

Comment: adding a `config.py` in the same directory as the `settings.py` file may clear this up.

Comment: Please provide project-structure (file-structure)

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your comments, you cloned this project from git.

Perhaps `config` is a local settings file you are meant to create yourself. Check the `README` and also check for a `config` example of some sorts